# Can I overwrite a designtime component reference at runtime?

Tags: delphi, object

I'm using a `TSQLConnection` component (`connDT`) on a data module only to fetch the fields to a `TSQLDataset`, `TDatasetProvider` and `TClientDataset` trio at design time that connects to my test database.
At runtime I need to change object instance of the designtime `TSQLConnection` (`connDT`) with a runtime object instance (`connRT`) connected to the production database.
I did it this way in the data module's `OnCreate` event:

`connDT := connRT;`

But when I open my `TClientDataset` object (trio), it still uses the test database (the `connDT` connection object settings are used). How can I overwrite a desigtime component reference at runtime?

Comment: No, you don't. Either use the existing connection (ConnDT) and change the connection name, or use your new connection (ConnRT) and change the `TSQLQuery.SQLConnection` to use that connectioni in your datamodule's OnCreate. You don't need to point one instance to another instance at all.

Comment: @KenWhite I know I can do it the way you said it, but it's not what I want to do.
I want to swap the SQLConnection object instance so I do not have to swap in all SQLDataset or already connect ConnDT with the production database configuration. It is not a SQLConnection exclusive issue, it is a matter of swapping the instance of the design-time component for a run-time instance.

Comment: That's not what you're supposed to do. If you won't face another problems, the original object that is instantiated for that design time component and that you overwrite loses its reference and won't get released.

Comment: But that's *wrong*. Why do you want to do something that is totally wrong and much more complicated than doing it the right way? Things are not difficult if you stop trying to do the incorrect thing and just do it correctly, and 99.9% of the problems new developers face is because they decide they need to do something that is wrong and then insist on doing it that way even after they're told it's wrong, and they always either end up doing it the right way in the end or asking dozens of questions about how to fix all the problems they've caused by insisting on doing things their way.

Comment: @Victoria I know the instance of connDT is not released, but I resolve this with connDT.Free before swapping the instance. But if I do this the SQLDataset will lose the SQLConnection set. I need to propagate the change to all SQLDataset.

Comment: Then do that with a loop in your code that does it at runtime. Geez! You're just not willing to listen.

Comment: I have developed systems with Delphi since 2004 and I have over 2400 clients using my system. I'm not a beginner. I just want to know if it's possible to do what I'm asking and how to do it. If it is not possible, I thank you anyway.

Comment: It might be possible, but do not do that. Besides, creating connection object at runtime requires parameter setup anyway, so why not just modify the existing one?

Comment: It's possible. It's also possible to cut off your fingers when your fingernails get too long, but I'd strongly advise against doing so. It's much easier to just find the nail clippers, and you'll really appreciate the effort to do it properly the next time you need to pick up a fork or a pen or use a keyboard.

Comment: You're facing an X-Y problem. You're asking how to do something you fundamentally should not be doing as the next step down a slippery slope to solve your ***root*** problem. You'd be better off taking a step back and asking about your root problem. I've seen connection components that support pooling, worked with custom connection components to provide external admin of connection settings. There are likely much better solutions to your ***root problem*** (whatever that may be) that don't require _fighting the framework_. So I suggest you abandon asking about Y and instead ask about X.

Comment: ConnDT already has all the rules to connect to the production database and is in a data module (the first data module created in my 13-year system) that is scattered throughout my system, causing many dependency and coupling problems. I created a singleton responsible for the creation of connRT that I can use throughout my system without causing coupling between the units of my system, but I do not want to have the job of pointing all the SQLDataset of my system (which are hundreds) to the connRT in time of execution.

Comment: Do you understand the problem? Is it possible to change the instance of a component to a run-time instance?  Sorry for my english, I'm using google translator.

Comment: I see your problem, so as others. But avoid that overwriting. Well, if you don't want to redesign, try at least `Assign` the `connDT` to `connRT`. That should make a deep copy of the object without losing the original reference.

Comment: Thank you @Victoria for your help, but `Assign` did not work, besides giving an `EConvertError`, I do not want a copy of the object. I do not understand why the assignment operator does not work in this case.

Comment: Actually the assignment operator works, when I inspect the connection parameters they are the same as run-time instance, but point to different memory addresses. I think it's a dbexpress feature that I can not get around. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Do not overwrite design time created object references this way. If you want to change connection of your database component(s) at runtime, do it either by modifying their [**SQLConnection**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.SqlExpr.TCustomSQLDataSet.SQLConnection) property, or by modifying the connection object's parameters (which is what I would prefer). So either this:

```
SQLDataSet1.SQLConnection := ConnRunTime;
```

Or something like this:

```
ConnDesignTime.Params.Values['Database'] := 'MyDatabase';
ConnDesignTime.Params.Values['User_Name'] := 'UserLogin';
ConnDesignTime.Params.Values['Password'] := 'Password';
ConnDesignTime.Open;
```

There are other ways, but the above ones are pretty easy.

Comment: Please see my comment on the question.